# SSMS Build: "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint"

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, build, ssms

I'm getting this error even thought I think my table correctly references a primary key. The Constituent_Gift table references 5 foreign keys but only triggers this error for the Gift table. I can't see why the Category table would work but the Gift table wouldn't. The exact error message is:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 12
> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "fk_giftid". The conflict occurred in database "SusanCurtis", table "dbo.Gift", column 'Gift_ID'.

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE Category
(
     Category_ID          NCHAR(4) CONSTRAINT pk_categoryid PRIMARY KEY,
     Category_Description NVARCHAR(50) CONSTRAINT nn_categorydescription NOT NULL
 );

CREATE TABLE Gift
(
    Gift_ID          NCHAR(1) CONSTRAINT pk_giftid PRIMARY KEY,
    Gift_Description NVARCHAR(20) CONSTRAINT nn_giftdescription NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE Constituent_Gift
(
    Constituent_Gift_ID NCHAR(6) CONSTRAINT pk_constituentgift PRIMARY KEY,
    Constituent_ID      NCHAR(6) CONSTRAINT fk_constituentid FOREIGN KEY 
        REFERENCES Constituent(Constituent_ID),
    Gift_ID             NCHAR(1) CONSTRAINT fk_giftid FOREIGN KEY
        REFERENCES Gift(Gift_ID),
    Fund_ID             NCHAR(4) CONSTRAINT fk_fundid FOREIGN KEY
        REFERENCES Fund(Fund_ID),
    Event_ID            NCHAR(2) CONSTRAINT fk_eventid FOREIGN KEY
        REFERENCES [Event](Event_ID),
    Category_ID         NCHAR(4) CONSTRAINT fk_categoryid FOREIGN KEY
        REFERENCES Category(Category_ID),
    Note                NVARCHAR(2000),
    Gift_Amount         MONEY CONSTRAINT nn_giftamount NOT NULL,
    Deductible_Amount   MONEY,
    Gift_Date           Date,
    Payment_Type        NVARCHAR(30),
    Anonymous_Gift      BIT
);
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the error message really says it all: obviously, that `INSERT` (which unfortunately you haven't shown) is trying to insert a value that violates the foreign key constraint `fk_giftid` - that's the foreign key between `Constituent_Gift.Gift_ID` and `Gift.Gift_ID` - which means you're trying to insert a row into `Constituent_Gift` with a value for `Gift_ID` that doesn't exist in the referenced `Gift` table.

And that's the **whole point** of a foreign key constraint - ensure you **only** ever insert **valid data** - that is present in the referenced table (here `Gift`).

Fix that value to be something that **is** present in the `Gift` table - and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

what data are you going to insert?
I also miss the schema for the table 'Constituent'

```
Constituent_ID                  NCHAR(6) CONSTRAINT fk_constituentid FOREIGN KEY 
        REFERENCES Constituent(Constituent_ID),
```